# Looking for the slideshow that is being used on http://www.ibm.com/us/en/

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I really like the effect that makes the image and the text slide in 2 different directions. I wonder if anyone know of any plugin (jquery if possible) that can do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be achieved with the Parallax effect.

Read this:

http://www.webrisorsa.info/collection-of-13-jquery-parallax-scrolling-website-inspirations/1050/